# Add a user in Mongo database with Scala driver

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am trying to add a user to a Mongo DB using Scala driver. I use the following code to do it:

```
val mongoClient = MongoClient()
val dbName = "..."

// create database
val db = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName)
val command = BsonDocument(Seq(
  "addUser" -> BsonString("dev"),
  "pwd" -> BsonString("password"),
  "roles" -> BsonArray(Seq(BsonString("readWrite")))
))
val observable = db.runCommand(command)

observable.subscribe(new CommandObserver[Document])

class CommandObserver[T] extends Observer[T] {
  override def onNext(result: T): Unit = println(s"Success: $result")

  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(s"Failure: $e")

  override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Done")
}
```

And here is the output that I receive:

> Failure: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error
>   -1: 'no such cmd: addUser' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: addUser", "bad cmd"
>   : { "addUser" : "dev", "pwd" : "", "roles" : ["readWrite"] } }

What is wrong with my code?